# Alternative sources for a topos theory description of zeroth order logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, category-theory, propositional-calculus, topos-theory

I have recently been reading Robert Goldblatt's fantastic book *Topoi: The Categorial Analysis of Logic*. Through chapters 6-8, Goldblatt produces a topos theoretic approach to zeroth order logic, where he generalises semantic valuations from boolean algebras. I am looking in particular for some other sources that talk about this topic. So far I have only been able to find resources on first order logic that are too advanced at my current stage.

Comment: Basically any book that talks about the truth functions on the subobject classifier is doing that, and almost every book on the subject does this. So the question is really which ones develop them in the way you're looking for. Are you able to be more specific about the topics you want to see covered?

Comment: I would specifically like to see result that link the subobject algebra of the terminal object in a topos to topos-valuations of sentences. Even more specifically, I would like to see the proof of the result that the following statements are equivalent:                                                                                 1. A sentence is valid in a topos E iff it is classically valid.                             2. In a topos E, for any sentence s, the sentence (s or (not s)) is valid in E.  3. The subobject algebra of the terminal object in the topos E is a boolean algebra.

Comment: 1 implies 2 is trivial.  For 2 equivalent to 3, I'd first look at a proof that a Heyting algebra is a Boolean algebra if and only if $x \vee (x \rightarrow \bot) = \top$ for all $x$, then generalize it to Heyting algebra objects in a category with finite products.  3 implies 1 should just be that the evaluation of a classically valid sentence in any Boolean algebra object of a category is equal to $\top$ (though the only if part of 1 could be problematic if you consider the topos with only one object, i.e. the topos of sheaves on the empty topological space).